# properly import default export from JSON module

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON translation file "./countries/es.json" in my Angular application that I want to import and loop through.

```
{
...
"Solomon Islands": "Islas Salomón",
"South Sudan": "Sudán del Sur",
...
}
```

I have `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in my `tsconfig.json` file, so in general import goes well.

```
import * as countries from './countries/es.json';
```

and if I access the object say `countries['Solomon Islands']` I get 'Islas Salomón' that is correct.

However if want to enumerate all countries:

```
const countries_keys = Object.keys(countries);
```

*countries_keys* is an array with one value 'default'. In order to obtain the country list I need to do:

```
const countries_keys = Object.keys(countries['default']);
```

My question - is there a way to do the import cleanly so I get the object exactly as in JSON file?

If I had the source file like:

```
{
countries: {
    ...
    "Solomon Islands": "Islas Salomón",
    "South Sudan": "Sudán del Sur",
    ...
    }
}
```

I could simply do:

```
import  { countries } from './countries/es.json';
```

but is there a clean way to import my original file as equivalent JSON object without the additional 'default' property.

Comment: are you using `ngx-translate`?

Comment: yes, I use ngx-translate, but this is not about translating per-se. I want to retrieve the value for other purpose. In fact I want to write a test to show that I have all the countries in translation file that I need - that match those in another file.

Comment: ok then you can use the http get approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in your `tsconfig.json`.

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

TS

```
import countries from './countries/es.json';
```

Comment: this is what op is doing how's this give ans to OP's question?

Comment: i think you missed the description part then read it you will get to know OP is doing the same thing already

Comment: your code will not even work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqvgrg

Comment: Please do not arbitrarily https://github.com/ngChina/ng-china-2019-web/blob/master/src/app/schedule/schedule.component.ts#L2

Answer (score 2):

import is not a good idea here later on if you want to move your file to some server you will need to rewrite the whole logic i would suggest to use [httpclient](https://angular.io/guide/http) get call here.So move you file to assets folder and then

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient){
this.http.get('assets/yourfilepath').subscribe(data=>{
   const countries_keys = Object.keys(data['countries']);
   console.log(data['countries'])//data is your json object here
})
}
```

Comment: thank you for the idea. I really did not count on files to be hosted elsewhere. On the other hand the other answer provides the answer to my exact question, so I accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

What worked form me was:

```
import countries from './countries/es.json';
```

This is the "default import"